# RACKET pause/continue button for game

Tags: button, canvas, racket, pause

I have a school project to create a version of Tetris in racket and I have to 
implement a pause/continue button which I'm stuck on.. My try:

```
(define *my-timer*
  (new timer%
       [notify-callback (lambda () (send *my-game-canvas* refresh))]))

(define *pause*
  (new button%
       [parent *my-window*]
       [label "Pause"]
       [callback (lambda ()
                   (send *my-timer* stop))]))
```

At the moment only the pause function is implemented but it doesn't work. I get an error message on the second define.

*my-game-canvas * is the canvas there the game graphics take place.

I appreciate all the answers.

/ Kasper

Edit:

The error I get:

```
initialization for button%: contract violation
  expected: (procedure-arity-includes/c 2)
  given: #<procedure:...0160511/game.rkt:61:17>
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: I added the error at the bottom of the post, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this clause:

```
   [callback (lambda ()
               (send *my-timer* stop))]
```

A callback needs to take two arguments: the button and the event.

Try this:

```
   [callback (lambda (button event)
               (send *my-timer* stop))]
```